# Resharper, ICloneable and never null

Tags: c#, resharper, icloneable

Resharper complains about the following code, saying that the last null check is redundant as the 'expression is always false':

```
  ICloneable data = item as ICloneable;
  if (data == null)
    throw new InvalidCastException("blah blah, some error message");

  object copy = data.Clone();
  if (copy == null) //  <-- this is where it complains.
    return default(T);
```

How does it know it can never be null?

Comment: well if it is true, you'll only return null.  My guess is *that's* what it's saying is redundant.  Just use `copy` and if it's null it'll return null and if it's not it'll return not null.

Comment: Servy, apologies, I edited the post to show the actual warning I get, which is "expression is always false".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ReSharper assumes that your object adheres to the contract of `ICloneable`, which says among other things that

> [The resulting clone must be of the same type as, or compatible with, the original instance.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

From the fact that `data` is checked to be non-null and the assumption that you return an object of the same or compatible type from your implementation of `ICloneable.Clone()` ReSharper concludes that `copy` is also non-null, triggering the warning.

Of course it is definitely possible to return `null` from `Clone`. However, returning `null` would be a coding error, so it is a good idea to skip that null check.

Comment: Well.. here's hoping everyone plays nice.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

***Notes to Implementers***
The ICloneable interface simply requires that your implementation of the Clone method return a copy of the current object instance.

If you're fulfilling the requirement of the contract, the `Clone` method should never return `null`.